# Render React bar chart from one-dimensional array (dates)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I’m getting an array of dates from an api like:

```
[‘Apr 14th, 2022’, ‘Apr 14th, 2022’, ‘Apr 12th, 2022’, ‘Apr 12th, 2022’, ‘Apr 11th, 2022’]
```

Notice multiple of the same dates in there. So each date is an “activity”, and what I’m trying to do is show a bar chart of activities for the last 14 days. I can get the current date with “new Date”. If the array has 3 of the same date, then 3 activities happened and the bar chart for that date should have 3 boxes on the bar chart.[image]

I can’t seem to find a bar chart that takes in a one-dimensional array of dates, how would I go about doing this? What I have currently tried is to group the array of dates by the day into an array of arrays, example: [ [14, 14], [12, 12], [11]]
And using that I can use the map function to iterate through each index of the array to render boxes depending on the length of the array. This is getting very ugly very fast, so looking for a small library where I can simple give it the array of dates and show me the bar graph. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

So after digging a little more I believe I found a minimal solution to your problem. I believe it would be difficult to find a library that deals with your exact situation, and the best course would be to try to format your data to fit with excepted parameters. Here is a snippet of code that I would believe would do that.
I use the package moment.js because it is widely used. https://momentjs.com/docs/

Here is the code snippet

```
const fourteenDaysAgo = moment().subtract(14, 'days')

let barChartArray = new Array(14).fill(0);

console.log(barChartArray)

dates.forEach((date) => {
    const dateAsMoment = moment(date, 'MMM Do, YYYY')
    const DateIsInFourteenDayRange = moment(dateAsMoment).isAfter(fourteenDaysAgo, 'day')

    if(DateIsInFourteenDayRange) {
      //initalizes a new moment that start at the beginning of the day
      //checks the differences in days between now and that date
      //uses that difference to populat the barChartArray

      const index = moment().startOf('day').diff(dateAsMoment, 'days')
      barChartArray[index]++
    }
})

console.log(barChartArray)
```

I created a jsfiddle you can try out here: https://jsfiddle.net/h2809Ljy/208/

Here are some of the console.log statements for random data.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 7, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1]
```

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 6, 4, 5, 8, 3, 6, 6, 2, 3]
```

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2]
```

I believe this could suit your needs, and it would allow a lot of flexibility with how you display the data. If you have any more questions about this code or how to start displaying it please let me know and I'd be happy to address them!

Original:

I would recommend checking out d3! It can be a powerful library for displaying data in react but doing something simple such as a bar chart is a relatively easy process.
d3

d3: https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3

simple bar chart tutorials:
https://observablehq.com/@d3/lets-make-a-bar-chart
https://blog.logrocket.com/data-visualization-in-react-using-react-d3-c35835af16d0/

One thing that can be initially confusing about using d3 with react is that they both have their own processes for managing elements, so you have to be conscientious of that while writing code (for something simple it probably won't affect anything).  I would recommend giving this article a read to understand what's going on with that (specifically the last few paragraphs). https://medium.com/noteableio/interactive-applications-with-react-d3-f76f7b3ebc71
https://betterprogramming.pub/5-steps-to-render-d3-js-with-react-functional-components-fcce6cec1411

Comment: Great library. My problem is a bit more specific then just displaying an array of data since my array is a) dates and b) multiple of the same dates and c) based on the current date and running back 14 days

So I would need to somehow show a bar chart by giving an initial value of the current date, and then giving the array of dates. If a date is not in the array, it would be 0 for that day.

Comment: @dhotlo2 Just curious, are there any options for the api request? Is there a limit on the size of the array or any limits on how far back the dates go?

Comment: nope no options, I just get back the array with dates in that format.

Comment: @dhotlo2 updated the post

Comment: Worked perfectly, much appreciated! I did a simple map function to go through the final array and just put the height of the div as the value in the array:

const finalchart = () => {

    return (
        barChartArray.map((activity, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <div className="graph-square" style={{height: (barChartArray[index])*5}}></div>
          </div>))
      )
  }

Comment: Glad I could help! Just so you know you should be conscientious of using indexes as keys.  https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys. As long as the data is changing a lot then you should be fine, which seems to be in your case. Just for future refence

Comment: Wanted to reach out again and mention that it seems this whole thing stopped working once I got into the next month (now May). The initial array is still correctly fetching activities, but if I do the part in the code:

`const fourteenDaysAgo = moment().subtract(14, 'days');

  let barChartArray = new Array(14).fill(0);

  console.log(barChartArray);
`

the console just shows the array with all 0's in it